# Dynamic option using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, combobox

I trying build dynamic `option` in `combo box`

In my case I use 4 combo box for example, and for option (1/2/3/4) if user pick option 1 then for the next combo box the option 1 will be gone, and only available (2/3/4).

b1 : 1,2,3,4

b2 : 1,2,3,4

b3 : 1,2,3,4

b4 : 1,2,3,4

If in b1 user select number 1 then for b2-b4 only have 3 option it's (2-3-4) and keep repeated until b4 (b2 select 3 then b3 & b4 only have 2 option it's (2 & 4), next if b3 select 4 then last combo box (b4) only have 1 option it's (2))

HTML :

```
<select id="b1" name="b1">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

    <select id="b2" name="b2"></select>
    <select id="b3" name="b3"></select>
    <select id="b4" name="b4"></select>
```

Javascript :

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var szTr ;
        var a = new Array('1','2','3','4');
        $( '#b1' ).on( 'change', function( e ) {
            for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            {
                if(a[i] == e.value)
                {
                    unset(a[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    szTr = szTr + "<option>" + a[i] + "</option>";
                }
            }
            $('#b2').append(szTr);
        });

        $( '#b2' ).on( 'change', function( e ) {
            // same code like b1
        });
    });
```

I try build in `array (1,2,3,4)` then check if same `unset` else `append` to next `combobox`.

But it's fail, and keep repeated the option every time select option, (2 times select ) the next combo box option (1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)  [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g13mmext/1/)

I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the current selected option.
2. Iterate through all the other select options excluding `this` select and `hide()` matched options

Try this:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $('select').not(this).find('option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == selected) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="b1" name="b1">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<select id="b2" name="b2">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<select id="b3" name="b3">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<select id="b4" name="b4">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/g13mmext/3/)

Comment: What do you mean by _previous options_ ?

Comment: Your answer is great, but still have some bug. sorry if i many request. (if first i pick 1) for the second i still can pick 1, and i can't change the option if i already select it, (first = 2, sec = 1 third = 3 fourth = 4, then change fourth = 1, after that the sec = null )and i must reload if want repair.

Comment: Requirement seems invalid to me.. I select `1` from first select..I will remove all `1` options from all other `select` now what if I select `2` from the first `select` ?